# Problem with ReadDirectoryChangesW filename when saving in Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, visual-studio-2019

I'm using ReadDirectoryChangesW to detect when a `.hlsl` file in a directory is changed. It works fine when saving the file with Notepad/Notepad++/VSCode, but when I try to save the file in Visual Studio 2019 I get a weird output. The folder name is preserved but the file name and extension is gibberish.

This is how my code looks. It's run on a separate thread that is invoked on application start.

```
void ShaderReloadWatcher::BeginWatching()
{
    m_thread = std::thread(&ShaderReloadWatcher::WatchShaderDirectory, this);
}
```

Thread main loop:

```
void ShaderReloadWatcher::WatchShaderDirectory()
{
    LPCTSTR shaderDir = "../Source/Shaders";
    HANDLE shaderFolderHandle = CreateFile(
        shaderDir,
        GENERIC_READ,
        FILE_SHARE_DELETE | FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING,
        FILE_FLAG_BACKUP_SEMANTICS | FILE_FLAG_OVERLAPPED,
        NULL);

    char notifyBuffer[1024];

    OVERLAPPED ovl = { 0 };
    ovl.hEvent = CreateEvent(NULL, TRUE, FALSE, NULL);
    DWORD error = ReadDirectoryChangesW(
        shaderFolderHandle,
        &notifyBuffer,
        sizeof(notifyBuffer),
        TRUE,
        FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
        NULL, &ovl, NULL);


    while (true)
    {
        DWORD result = WaitForSingleObject(ovl.hEvent, 0);

        switch (result)
        {
        case WAIT_TIMEOUT:
        {
            break;
        }

        case WAIT_OBJECT_0:
        {
            DWORD bytesTransferred;
            GetOverlappedResult(shaderFolderHandle, &ovl, &bytesTransferred, FALSE);

            OnDirectoryFileChange(notifyBuffer);

            ResetEvent(ovl.hEvent);

            DWORD error = ReadDirectoryChangesW(
                shaderFolderHandle,
                &notifyBuffer,
                sizeof(notifyBuffer),
                TRUE,
                FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_LAST_WRITE,
                NULL, &ovl, NULL);

            break;
        }

        }
    }

    CloseHandle(shaderFolderHandle);
}
```

OnDirectoryFileChange:

```
void ShaderReloadWatcher::OnDirectoryFileChange(char* buffer)
{
    DWORD offset = 0;
    FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION* fileNotifyInfo = nullptr;
    char fileName[1024];

    do 
    {
        memset(fileName, NULL, sizeof(fileName));
        fileNotifyInfo = reinterpret_cast<FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION*>(&buffer[offset]);

        WideCharToMultiByte(CP_ACP, NULL, fileNotifyInfo->FileName, fileNotifyInfo->FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR), fileName, sizeof(fileName), NULL, NULL);

        printf("%s\n", fileName);

        offset += fileNotifyInfo->NextEntryOffset;
    } while (fileNotifyInfo->NextEntryOffset != 0);
}
```

This is the output I get when I save (once) using Notepad++:

```
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl
```

I learned that it's printed multiple time due how text editors write to the file, so that is expected.

However, when saving with Visual Studio, I get this.

```
D3D11\sfpwwek3.vs4~
D3D11
D3D11
D3D11
D3D11
```

The folder name (D3D11) looks fine, but the filename is all gibberish. It's also different gibberish every time:

```
D3D11\5uuwurye.nel~
D3D11
D3D11
D3D11
D3D11
```

The encoding is set to Western European (CP 1252), and I've tried using different ones like Unicode (CP 65001), but I still get the same result.

I've watched the `fileNotifyInfo->FileName` value and it seems to be gibberish from the start, so nothing seems to be wrong with the `WideCharToMultiByte` conversion that is causing this issue.

Any help with understanding this problem is very much appreciated, thank you!

Comment: Could it be a temporary filename? They are often generated with random characters. If you let the program run while you close VS, will it change to something recognizable? Perhaps you should turn on sniffing for **all** directory changes too, just to see more clearly what's going on.

Comment: loop is wrong, why you at all open folder in asynchronous mode instead synchronous, file name - is not 0 terminated - so use %s is wrong. you not check for errors

Comment: @TedLyngmo I just tried it by adding the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` flag and it seems you are correct! It's now outputting a lot more stuff, including the correct filename. Thank you!

Comment: @soomi Great. :-)

Comment: @RbMm I'll have another look at the loop, thanks. File name is 0 terminated because I'm doing a memset to NULL before copying the values.

Comment: @soomi - you must not copy it - for what ?! and you not check actual length of file. if it longer than your buffer ? loop is wrong. usage of api is wrong

Comment: @RbMm Did this title say code review? I appreciate your feedback but honestly was just curious about the problem itself. I am copying it because I need the 1-byte character format for later use. Yes I'm not checking if the filename is longer than 1024(!) characters because I don't initially go for perfect code quality when using an API I haven't used before. I already said I was taking another look at the implementation, but thank you.

Comment: `WaitForSingleObject(ovl.hEvent, 0);` - really ok ? already not say about another things

Comment: @soomi Even if you didn't ask for code review, for the rest of us we appreciate errors being pointed out because people may be using this thread as reference in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem solved - thanks to @Ted Lyngmo.

I was only listening to write changes, and it seems Visual Studio was first writing to a temp filename, then renaming it to the correct one. I added the `FILE_NOTIFY_CHANGE_FILE_NAME` and now the output looks like this:

```
D3D11\cn42zizu.cht~
D3D11\cn42zizu.cht~
D3D11
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl~RF62be0e8e.TMP
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl~RF62be0e8e.TMP
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl~RF62be0e8e.TMP
D3D11
D3D11\cn42zizu.cht~
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl
D3D11
D3D11\light_pixel.hlsl~RF62be0e8e.TMP
D3D11
```

Lots of messages, but the correct name is there!

Comment: In your print output, you might want to include the value of the `FILE_NOTIFY_INFORMATION::Action` field in your output so you can see which event is a write and which event is a rename, eg: `printf("%u: %s\n", fileNotifyInfo->Action, fileName);`

Comment: And FYI, you don't need `WideCharToMultiByte()`, `printf()` can print Unicode strings if you use `%S`, `%ls`, or `%ws` instead of `%s`, eg: `printf("%u: %.*S\n", fileNotifyInfo->Action, fileNotifyInfo->FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR), fileNotifyInfo->FileName);` Or you could just use `wprintf()` instead, eg: `wprintf(L"%u: %.*s\n", fileNotifyInfo->Action, fileNotifyInfo->FileNameLength / sizeof(WCHAR), fileNotifyInfo->FileName);`

Comment: @Remy Lebeau Thank you. I need the string conversion for later use, but it's super useful to know that `printf` works for unicode strings, I'll remember it for later!